# select box plugin with AngularJS only

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

What is the best select box in angular only (No dependency from jQuery)?

I have seen lots of select box in jQuery, but this time I do my
project only in angular.

Thank you

Comment: This question is off topic.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: "4.Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1):

You could use, for example:

- Bootstrap dropdown in an Angular way: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown
- Angular material select component: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select
- another Angular module which does that:
  http://jseppi.github.io/angular-dropdowns/